# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples. Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am running this convolutional neural network model on gcolab. My goal is text classification. Here is my code and error:

```
# sequence encode
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_docs)

# pad sequences
max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in train_docs])
Xtrain = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

# define training labels
ytrain = array([0 for _ in range(900)] + [1 for _ in range(900)])


# load all test reviews
food_docs = process_docs('/content/drive/MyDrive/CNN_moviedata/data/food', vocab, False)
location_docs = process_docs('/content/drive/MyDrive/CNN_moviedata/data/location', vocab, False)
price_docs = process_docs('/content/drive/MyDrive/CNN_moviedata/data/price', vocab, False)
service_docs = process_docs('/content/drive/MyDrive/CNN_moviedata/data/service', vocab, False)
time_docs = process_docs('/content/drive/MyDrive/CNN_moviedata/data/time', vocab, False)
test_docs = food_docs + location_docs + price_docs + service_docs + time_docs
# sequence encode
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_docs)
# pad sequences
Xtest = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
# define test labels
ytest = array([0 for _ in range(100)] + [1 for _ in range(100)])

# define vocabulary size (largest integer value)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())

# compile network
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

Here is my model summary output:

Model: "sequential_1"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 41, 100)           415400

---

conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 34, 32)            25632

---

max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 17, 32)            0

---

flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 544)               0

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5450

---

## dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 11

Total params: 446,493
Trainable params: 446,493
Non-trainable params: 0

---

None

Here is my error that occurs when running the last cell

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-fa9c5ed3e39a> in <module>()
      2 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
      3 # fit network
----> 4 model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=2)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1527           label, ", ".join(str(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(single_data)))
   1528     msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1529     raise ValueError(msg)
   1530 
   1531 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 9473
  y sizes: 1800
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

Pretty new to working with CNN, I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474081/valueerror-data-cardinality-is-ambiguous-make-sure-all-arrays-contain-the-same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your training data only consists of 1,800 labels however your training inputs are 9,473.

```
>>> ytrain = np.array([0 for _ in range(900)] + [1 for _ in range(900)])

>>> ytrain.shape
(1800,)
```

Assuming that you actually want to create 50% 0's and 50% 1's for your labels, you need to change this to something like:

```
ytrain = np.array([0 for _ in range(len(Xtrain)//2)] + [1 for _ in range(len(Xtrain)//2)])
```

So this will create an array with half the labels of xtrain being 0's and the other half being 1's.

**Update**

For uneven datasets this might be better as it splits around the middle index so should handle odd lengths:

```
length = len(Xtrain)
middle_index = length//2

ytrain = np.array([0 for _ in range(len(Xtrain[:middle_index])) + [1 for _ in range(len(Xtrain[middle_index:]))])
```

Comment: That makes sense. I did make this change, however I am still getting the same error. The error this time includes: `ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 9473
  y sizes: 9472
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.` It seems to be uneven by one. Is there anything I could change further to prevent this (even if that means removing data)? Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!