# What to input in Keras.model.fit as Y and how do I fit different dimensions batches of data to Keras model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have some data and I try to work with it using Keras model. TLDR

**1.** What is the purpose of second parameter in model.fit(), and what is the purpose of **validation_data** parameter? I'm putting my ground_truth in **y** and I have nothing to put in **validation_data**, which is causing inability to use **callbacks** parameter

**2.** How do I use batches for below data structure?

My data consists of pairs of numpy arrays:

- training_data, shape (**x**,128)
- ground_truth (probability score), shape (**x**,)

where **x** differs between 3000-35000 depends on file, but it's the same for both arrays.

As previous research have found Convolution model fits best for my purpose I've created a model, with inputs (128,128,1) and returning single probability score for each mentioned **x**

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Convolution2D(16, (3, 3),padding='valid',input_shape=(128, 128, 1),strides=2,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_amount),bias_regularizer=l2(reg_amount)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
       #Some other layers
model.add(layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_amount),bias_regularizer=l2(reg_amount)))
model.add(layers.Activation('linear'))

model.build()
model.summary()

optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(loss='msle', optimizer=sgd)
```

Then I tried to fit this model and I was unable to do it using batches. I've put training_data as first parameter and ground_truth as second:

```
    spec_file = np.load ('data.npy')              
    anno_file = np.load ('ground_truth.npy')

    hist = model.fit(spec_file, anno_file,batch_size=128,verbose=0,)
```

And I'm getting below error message:

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
> x sizes: 128
> y sizes: 9801
> Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

I tried swapping dimensions, transposing but error message is the same.

I worked around it using for loop taking only one batch from each array, getting (128,128) and (,128) shapes and it caused fit function to work:

```
for n in range (0,(np.shape(anno_file[0])-128),1):
        mel_spect = np.array(spec_file[0:128,n:n+128])      #(128,128)
        mel_spect = mel_spect[np.newaxis, ...]              #(1,128,128)

        ground_truth = np.array(anno_file[n:n+128])         #(128,)
        ground_truth = ground_truth[np.newaxis, ... ]       #(1,128,)

        hist = model.fit(mel_spect, ground_truth, verbose=0 ) 
        losses.append(hist.history['loss'] )
```

So basically I'm fitting this model thousands of times for every single analyzed file, which I have a feeling, is not right. I should be able to push this data in batches but I don't know how. I also feel my understanding of fit() function is wrong.

Please advise on how will you fit those data into keras because I have no idea at all after days of trying. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st question**

If I correctly understood your first question, I think you are confusing the training ground-truth with the validation data.

The second parameter in `model.fit()` is used for specifying the **training ground-truth**, as you mentioned, for your **train** data. This set must be consistent with the one you specified in the `x` argument. From the [Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> y: Target data. Like the input data x, it could be either Numpy array(s) or TensorFlow tensor(s). It should be consistent with x

The `validation_data` parameter refers to a completely different thing. Here, you specify a sub-set from your whole data (and corresponding labels) that will just be used to compute the training metrics obtained for each epoch.

Maybe with an example it could be easier to understand. Suppose that you are trying to classify images of cats and dogs. Each image can just contain either a dog or a cat, so its image labels can be a simple integer: 0 for dogs and 1 for cats. Here, `x` refers to the images, and `y` to the integer labels.

If you want to use the `validation_data` argument, you need to do a previous split (see [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) method from sklearn module), specifying the train-test ratio. As a result, you receive a tuple with 4 values: `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test`. Those contained in `x_test, y_test` can be directly fed to the `validation_data` argument.

**2nd question**

This issue has already been treated in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474081/valueerror-data-cardinality-is-ambiguous-make-sure-all-arrays-contain-the-same). Check it, maybe it could help you ;).